# What does it mean to permute the subdiagonal entries of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

\begin{pmatrix}1 &0 &0& 0 \\
2& 1& 0& 0\\
3& 0& 1& 0\\
4& 0& 0& 1
\end{pmatrix}
can turn into 
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 0& 0& 0\\ 
4& 1& 0& 0\\
3& 0& 1& 0\\
2& 0& 0& 1
\end{pmatrix}
In this case, for the top most matrix, the sub-diagonals are [2,0,0], [3,0] and [2]. How can we rearrange these sub-diagonals when their sizes differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the phrase "subdiagonal" refers exclusively to the first diagonal below the main diagonal. So permuting the entries of the subdiagonal would be permuting just the entries of $[2,0,0]$ within that sub diagonal.